# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.04 in graphics mode or safe graphics mode

Tags: 12.04, boot, intel-graphics, xserver

I can boot into ubuntu only in tty screen non-graphics mode only.
My machince is with intel onboard DG33 graphics.
I have already run these commands without any error.

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get --purge xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

All commands run fine, but in normal mode it just hangs in the middle and in recovery mode it boots in to black login screen.
Thanks